# Scrolling through "touchmove" is choppy

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-website

I wanted "position:fixed" on mobile devices (I have an Android one) - and this doesn't exist.
I faked it by creating two divs the heights of which summed to the height of the screen (using JS) and added `touch` listeners to the bottom div. The events would adjust the scrollTop value. This was a copy of an old "touchScroll.js".

The scrolling works successfully, I even added sling feel. However, the entire scroll is very choppy as compared to when the OS scrolls the view of the window.

I've read on random places, and somewhere here to add `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` and `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);` css bits to solve this chop. I tried that on the div itself, on the body, only the backface part, only the transform etc... all permutations... nothing helped. The chop still existed, and the tricks stopped my keyboard from appearing in `input`s

I tried to create an internal div within my scrolling one, and instead of adjusting the `scrollTop` value I would just move the internal div by making it `position:absolute` and adjusting it's `top`. This made no difference.

Is there any solution to beat the chop?
Example is here: http://mobile.phantasyrpg.com/so-example

Comment: Ended up disabling custom JS for newer phones. Modern mobile browsers automatically handle scrollable divs, and do that much better than any JS substitute I was ever able to find.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there might not be a solution for this, Android browsers are known for their poor rendering performance. Different Android version/device/browser combinations will show different performance and compatibility, as a matter of fact, your example runs quite smooth on my Android 4.0.4 Chrome, but not even functional on the factory browser.

As a general rule, always try to use CSS transformations, and only after other properties (like scrollTop), as transformations are often hardware accelerated. (As it's the case in iOS Mobile Safari, and modern Android browsers).

I suggest you to try the latest version of [TouchScroll](https://github.com/davidaurelio/TouchScroll/) or [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll), because they both use CSS transformations, and may contain other optimizations as well.

The `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);` setting is usually used to enforce hardware acceleration, and should be used on the element that is changing/moving (the content div in your case). However if you use new versions of scroll libraries, they will overwrite `-webkit-transform` property anyway. The `-webkit-backface-visibility` is only appropriate if `-webkit-transform` is also applied on the element, setting it to `hidden` may resolve unwanted flickering or may provide performance gain in some cases.

Comment: What could I say? Develop for iphone? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Is supposed to make things smoother. Not sure if it works on older Androids

Comment: I'll give it a shot. never saw that during my hunt for the solution